# log4j dsl in grails 2.x with additivity flag

Tags: grails

Can I do the following with the additivity flag and appenders for a given log level?

```
log4j =
{
  appenders
  {
    ...
  }
  root
  {
    debug additivity: true, 'stdout', 'errorlog'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the additivity flag on the root logger. Additivity isn't inherited (setting `foo` to additivity `false` doesn't automatically cause `foo.bar` to be `false` as well), it is simply set to `true` for all loggers except those where you've explicitly set it to `false`.

Since the additivity flag controls inheritance of appenders from a logger's parent it wouldn't make sense to permit an additivity setting on the root logger, which by definition has no parent.